Definition of an integral function
I am new to theta functions, and reading about them in Elliptic Functions and Applications by Derek F. Lawden it is stated that these theta functions are "integral functions". What is the definition of this term? The book does not define it and It seems that I can't find the definition on the internet.


In this case, "integral" means "entire", i.e. that it's everywhere complex differentiable. And also, in this case I assume that "everywhere" means "in the upper half-plane".
